# Handling events on many elements with one for loop using closure works, but why?

Tags: javascript, events, closures

I have this code to assign event listeners to a bunch of articles:

```
var toggleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('article > div > span');
var articles = document.querySelectorAll('article');

for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    var article = articles[i];
    var button = toggleButtons[i];

    article.classList.toggle('article-closed');

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      article.classList.toggle('article-closed');

      if (button.innerHTML === "Lees meer") {
        button.innerHTML = "Sluiten";
      } else {
        button.innerHTML = "Lees meer";
      }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

This works great! But I can't find how it works anywhere... I hope someone can explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: The 

`(function(i) {`

and

`})(i);`

parts, I looked at many stackoverflow answers and many say this is the solution. And it works great. But I can't figure out why because nobody explains it.

Comment: [Please explain closures, or binding the loop counter to the function scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776792/please-explain-closures-or-binding-the-loop-counter-to-the-function-scope) When you invoke a function *(which is what is happening)*, it creates a new variable scope. So now you have new variables being created in the same scope as the event handler, so the handler can reference them without the next iteration overwriting them..